# Why $U(p^m) \oplus U(q^n)$ is not cyclic

Tags: group-theory

I tried to solve the following exercise:

Let $p,q$ be odd primes and $n,m$ positive integers. Explain why $U(p^m) \oplus U(q^n)$ is not cyclic.

I solved the question as follows:

We have $U(p^m) \oplus U(q^n) \cong U(p^m q^n)$. It is a theorem that $U(n)$ is cyclic if and only if $n=2,4,p^k,2p^k$. But $p^m q^n$ is not of this form.

The problem is that this fact I use does not appear in the book. The only fact that is mentioned is:

$$ U(st)=U(s)\oplus U(t)$$
when $s,t$ are coprime and $U(p^n) = \mathbb Z_{p^n -p^{n-1}}$.

> Is it possible to solve this exercise without using the fact when
>   $U(n)$ is cyclic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Undoubtedly there are many ways to skin this cat. The first that occured to me is the following plan:

1. You have undoubtedly seen the fact that a cyclic group of order $n$ has a unique subgroup of order $d$ for all factors $d\mid n$.
2. How many subgroups of order two can you find in $U(p^m)\oplus U(q^n)$?

Comment: It was so easy! I did not see that! Thank you for your answer! (I can find zero subgroups of order two)

Comment: Wrong. If there are no subgroups of order two, then the order of the group should be an odd number, but it is even. Look more carefully.

Comment: Oops, right. Each factor has a subgroup of order two therefore the product has at least three subgroups of order two therefore the product cannot be cyclic! Thank you for your help!

Comment: Correct :-) ${}{}$